# How to clear the board

Tags: python

The issue I'm having is how can I make my game stop "re-printing" the board game and not show the board again and again every round/turn in the console? I want it to change the "X" in the 1st board and not reprint the board with the "X".

Here's the code:

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

print ship_row
print ship_col

for turn in range(4):
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
        print "Turn", turn + 1
        print_board(board)

print "Game Over"
```

Comment: next time go right into the question and don't write an history about your life :)
For dynamic in-line changing, you can look around stdout methods.
Or you can just clear the screen before reprinting the screen, because the previous way is a bit hard but will make you learn a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I will do that next time!
Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: @J.Pinheiro I really liked your history :)  , it was a Deja Vu :'(, once I also learnt the same battleship from Codeacademy and thought only if sombebody would tell me how to make it graphic and port to andorid and stuff. So that answers would have definitely helped you, like from rodrigo about pygame.

Comment: I'm very excited to be honest, been 2 weeks and not losing the interest, though I'm very lost, because there are many things I didn't knew that existed, like this pygame, curses, stdout, searching a bit, this is a world of stuff to do!
Luckely, later this year, I will have a fully functional game hehe

Btw, how can I give reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go simple, you can clear the screen with this line:

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

And then quickly repaint the board.

For more advanced console management, you can use the `curses` module. It is not very easy to use, but it will let you do a lot of fancy stuff. It is actually thin binding of the C `curses` library, so you may find a lot more documenatation if you search for the C one.

If you want to go graphic, the standard library is `pygame`. It is a not-so thin binding of the popular SDL library, but you will find a lot of `pygame` examples out there.

Comment: What does that do precisely?

Comment: @J.Pinheiro: Do you mean that `print`? It prints in the console the escape sequence `ESC[2J`, that in ANSI-compatible terminals (most of them but Windows) will clear the screen. For more details see `man console_codes`.